# How to combine guard clauses and database calls in asynchronous NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

NodeJS 6.9.3

Suppose we were working in a synchronous language like PHP or Ruby. We would often see this pattern:

```
$all_results = [];
$array_of_words = get_relevant_words();

for ($i=0; $i < count($array_of_words); $i++) {

     $word = $array_of_words[$i];

     if (len($word) < 3) {
        continue;
     }

     $results = database_call($word);
     $all_results = array_merge($all_results, $results);    
}
```

Looping over an array, making database calls, and having some guard clauses which occasionally forces the code to skip certain calls -- this is a standard pattern, you find it in nearly all code bases.

Since NodeJS is asynchronous, we give up certain kinds of control flow, and we have to work to get them back.

I've been working on this issue for the last week and I mostly figured out how to do this, but the code I have is so extremely ugly that I'm sure there must be a more idiomatic way to do this in NodeJS. I'm curious what the idiomatic approach is?

Right now, instead of a loop, I have recursive callbacks:

```
    return database_queries.profiles(word, array_of_words_from_string_from_api_call, index_to_read, map_of_profiles)
        .then(function(results_from_database) {

            map_of_profiles = Object.assign( map_of_profiles, results_from_database ); 

            if (index_to_read < array_of_words_from_string_from_api_call.length - 1) {
                return database_queries.profiles(word, array_of_words_from_string_from_api_call, index_to_read + 1, map_of_profiles);

            } else {
                return map_of_profiles; 
            }
```

That function keeps calling itself until the index has reached the last item in the array.

Inside of the database query function, I have my guard clause:

```
            if (!search_term || search_term == "") {
            var thenable = { then: function(resolve) {
            return new Error ({
                              "message" : "The search term was empty so we did not run the database query.",
                              "array_of_words_from_string_from_api_call" : array_of_words_from_string_from_api_call,
                              "index_to_read" : index_to_read,
                              "map_of_profiles" : map_of_profiles
                              });
            }};
            return thenable; 
            }
```

This is where my code starts to get really ugly: I'm passing in variables such as `array_of_words_from_string_from_api_call` just so that I can return them in the error, just so they will be available in the catch() block which catches this error.

Worst of all, instead of using my catch() block to handle real errors, I've duplicated all of the recursive code above, which keeps calling `database_queries.profiles()`.

Returning an error was the only way I could find to imitate a traditional guard clause. And the only place I could handle this error is in the catch block.

There has to be a less ugly way to do this in NodeJS. Can anyone tell me what the idiomatic approach is?

Comment: use `async` lib and it's `async.eachLimit`. keep in mind `each`, `parallel` is not recommended if You've big amount of items - due network, db load, better use `parallelLimit`, `eachLimit` and define for example 5 operations at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use async library. It allows you to run asynchronous code in parallel or in defined order (when calls depend on each other).
Take a look at [async documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html)

In your case you can use async.each  [each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each), it will execute your function on every element in the array in parallel and eventually will call the final callback.

In your case you may consider using [eachLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit) which allows you to limit the number of parallel requests, in order not to crash the DB with lots of requests.

```
const processWords = (words, done, limit = 5) => {
  const results = [];
  async.eachLimit(
    words, // iteratable variable
    limit, // concurrency limit
    (word, next) => { // item processor
      if (word.length < 3) {
        return next();
      }

      database_call(word, (error, result) => {
        if(error) return next(error);
        if(result) results.push(result);
        next();
      });
    }, 
    error => done(error, results) // at the end of iteration
  );
};

const words = ['hello', 'world'];
processWords(words, (error, result) => {
  console.log(error, result);
});
```